# Gradle task not ran when subproject task ran

Tags: c++, gradle

I have a gradle c/cpp project where it has rootProject/project/subProject

In my root build.gradle I have

```
ext.libFolder = rootDir.toString + '/lib/'
subprojects {
  build.doLast {
   copy {
    from fileTree ( buildDir.getCanonicalPath() ).files
    into rootProject.ext.libFolder
    include '*.so'
    include '*.a'
   }
  }
}
```

This works perfectly when I do: gradle build but if I do gradle :project:subProject:build it does not work... What do I need to change to make this work no matter how I call the build task?

On a side note we are trying to make all subProject build.gradle files as bare minimal as possible, simple as possible, and structurally the same as possible, as we have over 780 of them.

edit: I have added in a clean task as shown below this way gradle will know the files have been cleaned. This however does not seem to effect the core issue where the build task when called any way other than gradle build does not run the doLast task.

```
clean {
  delete rootProject.ext.includesFolder
  delete rootProject.ext.libfolder
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the `build.doLast{}` in an `afterEvaluate{}` block.

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate{
        build.doLast {
            copy{
                from fileTree ( buildDir.getCanonicalPath() ).files
                into rootProject.ext.libFolder
                include '*.so'
                include '*.a'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because you want to add the doLast functionality after the subproject build task is available.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. I'm not sure if it due to how I am currently cleaning the libs folder or something else. I'm going to try and come up with a clean task for the libs folder where it deletes the files from the libs folder that are associated with a given project, that way gradle will know they have been cleaned vs just deleting them.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't paying attention to the contents of your task. I was only looking at extending build.doLast in a way that works reliably when called on the subproject. When you say, it does not work, can you give some details about what is failing?

Comment: when gradle build is ran it will copy .so and .a files to the lib folder. When I run gradle :_QT_CORE:QT_MAIN:build it will attempt to build the QT_MAIN subproject and any projects it depends on but it will fail because it does not do the do last which will copy the need .so and .a files into the lib folder even if I include a --continue. If I first run a full build using gradle build then the .so and .a files will be copied into the lib folder. After which I can use gralde :_QT_CORE:QT_MAIN:build or install.

Comment: When you run `:_QT_CORE:QT_MAIN:build`, do .so and .a files even exist in `rootProject.ext.libFolder`? because you didn't build the root project.

Comment: If a clean has been run then they will not exist. The idea is that A depends on B then B.build will be called and when B.build is done it will copy the .so and .a files to libs then run A.build. Is this not correct?

Comment: are you missing `copy{}` in the code that you posted?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code. We work on a private network so I had to retype it for here ;(

Comment: I see the problem you're describing, when I do not use the afterEvaluate block, but works fine for me once I include afterEvaluate. See sample here: https://github.com/foragerr/SO-35181097-Gradle-Subproject

Comment: I see what the issue is now but am not sure how to fix it. When I call something like :_QT_CORE:QT_MAIN:build it does not actually run the build task for any project expect for the specific task and only runs compile for all other task.

Comment: When you call build on a leaf project, the parent project is configured, but it's build task is not executed. This is normal gradle behavior. If you call build task on parent, all subproject build tasks are executed as well. Why is this a problem though? you're building subproject and copying it's binaries to parent project folders right?

Comment: Yes, but the subproject depends on other subprojects that may have not been built or more likely have changed.

Comment: The `buildNeeded` task will run `build` in the target project and all projects that it depends on. That may be the simplest option.

I'm a bit surprised that `build` only triggers the compilation of the upstream projects and not the linking. In Java projects, `build` results in `jar` (the packaging step) being executed.